# How can I get elements of a struct as a type boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

I have a struct like this

```
struct Observation
{   
  observation_id id;
  ObsVector z;
  ObsMatrix R;
  double confidence;

  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Observation> Ptr;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<const Observation> ConstPtr;
};
```

So I have a file EFK.h where I need a struct Observation

```
 class EFK
 {
   public:
    Observation::Ptr observer (new Observation);
  /// Something else
 }
```

So in the EFK.cpp file I want to use some variables of the struct

```
void EFK::update (ObsVector input, ObsVector delta)
{
   /// Some stuff
   input.z = observer->z -delta.z;
}
```

but when I compile I get this

```
*error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
     input.z = observer->z - delta.z;*
                       ^
```

And I don't know why . This is has something to be with the boos::shared_ptr?

Thank you

Comment: I think it's something to do with `Observation::Ptr observer (new Observation);` declaring a function and not a variable. (Although that looks like an invalid function declaration to me)

Comment: @immibis Clang's policy of "try to fix it and keep going" for saner error messages seems to be the culprit here. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ot3kY4jkk17ch7Lk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a default value for attribute `observer`, write:

```
class EFK
{
public:
   Observation::Ptr observer = new Observation;
   /// Something else
};
```

Or:

```
class EFK
{
public:
   EFK() : observer(new Observation)
   {}

   Observation::Ptr observer;
   /// Something else
};
```

The syntax of `Type name(...)`, is the one of a function declaration.

Comment: sintax. Pun of the day

Comment: What have you said? xD

Comment: You can't do option 1. `boost::shared_ptr` does not have an overloaded assignment operator for a plain pointer (ie. `boost::shared_ptr<Type> ptr = new Type;` is a syntax error.) But the second option works.

Answer (score 0):

I might read the question wrong - it's not entirely clear.

Responding **just** to the title ***"How can I get elements of a struct as a type `shared_ptr`"*** you can and should use aliasing-constructors of shared pointer:

```
Observation::Ptr p = std::make_shared<Observation>();
// take shared_ptr to a **member** of p
std::shared_ptr<ObsVector> member_z(p, &p->z);
```

This shared the ownership of the shared_ptr for `p`. Meaning that `p` will not be deleted until `member_z` is reset/destructed either:

```
p.reset(); // Observation stays alive
std::cout << "p has been reset\n";
member_z.reset(); // destructor of Observation runs now!
std::cout << "member_z has been reset\n";
```

Prints

```
p has been reset
~Observation
member_z has been reset
```

### LIVE DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4b33aa743aae014)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct ObsVector { 
    double x,y,z; 
    ObsVector operator-(ObsVector const& o) const { return { x-o.x, y-o.y, z-o.z }; }
};

struct Observation
{   
    ~Observation() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

    ObsVector z;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Observation> Ptr;
};

int main() {
    Observation::Ptr p = std::make_shared<Observation>();
    // take shared_ptr to a **member** of p
    std::shared_ptr<ObsVector> member_z(p, &p->z);

    p.reset(); // Observation stays alive
    std::cout << "p has been reset\n";
    member_z.reset(); // destructor of Observation runs now!
    std::cout << "member_z has been reset\n";
}
```